# Weird Gridsplitter resizing behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

Got his XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="correctionTests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsMainMenu="True">
            <MenuItem Header="_Ouvrir" Click="Open_Click"/>
        </Menu>
        <GroupBox Header="Tests : " VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="testList"/>
        </GroupBox>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Width="5"
                      Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
        <UserControl x:Name="userContent" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now the problem is that the size of the controls on the column 0 is diminishing when i pull the gridsplitter to the RIGHT, on the other hand the size of the controls of the column 0 is increasing while pulling the gridsplitter to the left.

I already found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880272/gridsplitter-to-resize-from-right-odd-behaviour) on stack that suggested to change the first column's width to Auto.

The problem is : if i do that, the controls does not resize anymore.

How can i do so that my controls get all the width available ? (with the expected gridsplitter behaviour) ?

Comment: If you set your second column from Auto to the fixed width it has anyway (5) and add `HorizontalAlignment` / `HorizontalContentAlignment` = `Stretch` to the `Grid` children do you still get the same behavior? Sorry I just don't have time to test.

Comment: Sadly it didn't changed anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your GridSplitter is on separate column, you have to 
set `ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"`

Comment: Why the downvote ? Is it not working ? I didn't have time to try this one yet.
If it was because it was a year old subject, since i didn't have any answer yet.... Well i'm still interested....

Comment: Solution worked in my case, still don't understand the downvote -_-' Thanks anyway